# How to install SQLite JDBC Driver?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I just want to use SQLite in a Java application. I found [sqlitejdbc](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) but how do I install it? I am on Ubuntu. I got the jar file. But I try:

```
jiewmeng@JM:~/Desktop$ java -jar ./sqlitejdbc-v056.jar 
no main manifest attribute, in ./sqlitejdbc-v056.jar
```

How do I use it then?

Comment: Did you read anything on the page you link to?

Comment: Oh, I missed this: `java -cp .:sqlitejdbc-v056.jar Test` is that what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to install it. Just add the jar to the classpath of your project