# Problems with SQLite JDBC driver under IntelliJ

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, intellij-idea

So, I've got a problem, similar to this one, but with a WebApplication running with JBoss on RHEL: [How to install SQLite JDBC Driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348157/how-to-install-sqlite-jdbc-driver) but I cannot find a solution.

My problem is: If I build my code with IntelliJ I can run it locally (A Windows PC) but can't run it under a RHEL server. It throws: "java.sql.SQLException: RouteToMyDataBase"

However if I build my code with NetBeans it run's under both OS (RHEL and Windows), sooo, I don't think my code's wrong at all and I think there's something to do with my classpath, or the way I'm building my "artifacts" with IntelliJ.

I tried by copying my libs inside /opt/jbosseap51/jboss-as/server/default/lib/ as suggested somewhere else here (I lost the Question)

Please, don't tell me to build my project with netbeans, because it is a huge application build using intelliJ and would be too difficult to migrate all the project. It is working ok, but recently while migrating our project to different machines through SVN happend this.

¿Is there anything else I have to configure?

Comment: Try to compare the artifacts produced by IDEA and NetBeans to see what is the difference, probably some classes are of a different version or some dependencies are missing.

Comment: Well, I've already did this and both projects look alike, in netbeans I add my library as usual, and in IDEA(IntelliJ) I've tried adding them to both, global Libraries and Module Librearies, with no luck.

Comment: How do you package the final artifact and link the dependencies into it? Via manifest or by unpacking all the classes in a single jar? If the first, check the manifest file contents inside the executable jar, ensure it's linking the correct driver version. See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html for details. Also note that global library has no effect unless it's explicitly added to the module dependencies. Don't forget about dependencies Scope, Provided libraries are not included in the jar.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow when I'm back to work, but yeah, this is what I was looking for. By the way, as you say, I think it has something to see with how I'm packaging my artifacts. Sorry by the question but I'm really new to IntelliJ (Not to programming) and some people left this project unexpectedly without any warnings or advice and I have to re-take it...

Comment: Okok, I'm getting very frustrated with this, It seems like none of my modules have a MANIFEST file so, how can I add it or configure my enviroment to make it find my LIB?

Comment: I am also checking if I can export it to net beans but seems like a titanic labor and not a very helpful one.

Comment: IDEA doesn't create manifest, you need to add it to your project and package to the artifact.

Comment: My problem's partially fixed. I build my project using a different computer and it build correctly. The only difference between both machines is the first one was a32 bit os Pc and the second one was a 64 bit pc.